# Heroku with Rails 5.2 Error When trying to Pull the Database from Heroku to local (pg:pull)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to replace my local DB with that from my live Heroku app.

My sausage fingers almost dropped my Heroku database instead of the local one, but I aborted almost immediately.  My live site is unaffected, but when I try to run this:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE MABsecret_development
```

I get this error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg16.04+1); pg_dump version: 11.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file
 ▸    pg_dump errored with 1
```

I've looked all over SO, but can't find a situation that parallels mine.  Can anyone help me get my Heroku to be "pullable"?  My local db is currently dropped and waiting!

Comment: are you running the same pg version on your local that is on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue once, and I noticed that I didn't have the same version of PG installed on my local, so I uninstalled it and then installed the same version that was on the heroku.

You can check the postgresql version on heroku by opening the `Heroku Postgres` from add-ons list.

Try pulling the database again, after re-installing the similar version. It worked for me!